# vscode invalid syntax error for dart and flutter after pressing the Ctrl+Shift+I short to format the code in readable form

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

I am using vscode in ubuntu for developing flutter application. I installed the flutter and dart extension for vscode. when I write code and keep it the same dirty format it doesn't take any syntax error -although it shouldn't- but after I reformat the code in a readable shape using Ctrl+Shift+i short-key vscode takes syntax error. However, when I close the file (here the .dart file) and re-open it, all errors is gone. You can see it more in the picture.[image] 
I don't know how to handle this kinda error.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have the Laravel Blade Spacer extension installed. This extension [accidentally reverses the order of edits](https://github.com/austenc/vscode-blade-spacer/blob/ae88ae1e82719c7b9fc088b93903285ac61b283a/src/extension.ts#L35) when handling a document edit event. VS Code then passes that mutated set of changes to other extensions (like Dart) which end up making incorrect edits (in this case, that are sent to the language server, so it gets an incorrect picture of what the file looks like).

This was fixed in VS Code (by preventing mutations to the array) in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88310, but has yet to be released.

For now, you'll need to either disable that extension or use VS Code Insiders. Once the next stable version of VS Code is out, the issue should disappear.